# How to retrieve coupon information in X-Cart 5.5

Tags: module, x-cart

How to get the information about the discount coupon that the customer used or entered during the checkout process in X-Cart version 5.5?

To get the coupon information such as coupon code, coupon amount or discount percentage, coupon type etc.

Comment: Hello. Could you please add info about what have you tried so far? Maybe a code you have tried and error you are getting?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please check \CDev\Coupons\Model\Order::getUsedCoupons method.